# What technique is used for slider in sublime text's website?

Tags: jquery, sublimetext

In sublime Text's website [(Sublime Text Website)](https://www.sublimetext.com), Slider part looks like a video. But when I inspect using chrome development tool, it shows image.
Can someone help me out what to do to make something similar like it ?

Comment: http://www.sublimetext.com/%7Ejps/animated_gifs_the_hard_way.html

Comment: Thank you for your response